# How to nest element of an object inside the same object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, nested-object

I created a form to get some info from User, and I want to move some of their info into a nested object. the reason why is to better organize my data later in front-end.

As a simple example, how to create the following "newInfo" out of "oldInfo" in JavaScript?

```
oldInfo = {
  name: 'John',
  Age: '32',
  friend1: 'Michael',
  friend2: 'Peter',
};

newInfo = {
  name: 'John',
  Age: '32',
  friends: {
    friend1: 'Michael',
    friend2: 'peter',
  },
};
```

I'm sure this must be a repeated and simple topic, but I couldn't find any as I didn't know what keyword to search for.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with spread operator:

```js
const { name, Age, ...friends } = oldInfo;
newInfo = { name, Age, friends };
```

It simply extracts all fields except `name` and `age` as `friends`.

**Example:**

```js
const oldInfo = {
  name: 'John',
  Age: '32',
  friend1: 'Michael',
  friend2: 'Peter',
};
const { name, Age, ...friends } = oldInfo;
const newInfo = { name, Age, friends };
console.log(newInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could explicitly assign it

```js
const oldInfo = {
  name: "John",
  Age: "32",
  friend1: "Michael",
  friend2: "Peter",
}

const newInfo = {
  name: oldInfo.name,
  Age: oldInfo.Age,
  friends: {
    friend1: oldInfo.friend1,
    friend2: oldInfo.friend2,
  },
}

console.log(newInfo)
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, but since the number of fields in `friend:name` are dynamic (the example above was simplified to better show my problem) I need to use a code rather than assigning them explicitly

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic number of `friend: name` key-value pairs and other properties that shouldn't be nested into `friends` then you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const oldInfo = {
  name: 'John',
  Age: '32',
  friend1: 'Michael',
  friend2: 'Peter',
};

const newInfo = Object.entries(oldInfo).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
  if(k.startsWith('friend')) {
    acc.friends ? acc.friends[k] = v : acc.friends = {[k]: v};
  } else {
    acc[k] = v;
  }
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(newInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, creative code, the only problem is that in my example I wrote above all keys start with friend (friend1, friend2...) yet in my actual problem there are other keys which are not alphabetically similar. This method though is very useful and I definitely use it in my other problems

Comment: @Babak Happy to help. You can update your question with the actual object if you want an answer for that.